# Finding documents where any attribute meet a given criteria

Tags: mongodb, find

Let's consider the following "Article" MongoDB document :

```
{ 
    "content" : "Helo World"
    "check" : {
        "grammar" : {
            "done" : true
            "result" : "fail"
        },
        "spelling" : {
            "done" : false
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to query all "Articles" documents from the collection where any of the `check`s objects have an attribute `"done" : false`.

I don't want to use a simple "OR" clause like this:

```
["$or"] = {
    { ["check.grammar.done"] = false },
    { ["check.spelling.done"] = false }
}
```

because I may add new `check`s in the future.

I couldn't find a syntax that would allow me to do this. I would expect something like `{ ["check.$any.done"] = false }` or like `{ ["check..done"] = false }`. Does something similar exists? How should I proceed?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, there is no easy way to do this without knowing the keys.

The best way would be to change your document structure a little bit:

```
{ 
    "content" : "Helo World",
    "check" : [{
        "type" : "grammar",
            "done" : true,
            "result" : "fail"
        },{
        "type" : "spelling",
            "done" : false
        }]
}
```

This way you can search it easily with `db.find({'check.done' : true})` . Moreover you can put an index on that field to make it super fast

Comment: Thanks, changing the structure was also what I was thinking.

Comment: And it's not every morning I get a MongoDb answer from Salvador Dali ;)

Comment: Have to go back to paint. See you soon. Glad that you know me :-)